# Problem while running Asterisk in Virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, asterisk

I have installed the Virtual box. So in that I have install debian OS in the Virtual machine. In that debian OS I have tried to install the Asterisk. That asterisk also installed successfully. But after installing the asterisk if I call registered number which is register in the extensions.conf file, that time asterisk is not working correctly.  In that extensions.conf file I have used the AGI.

Whether we can run the Asterisk in Virtualbox or not. But if we install asterisk in the separate machine, if we use the AGI in the extensions.conf file it is working fine. What is the problem, why it is not running in the Virtual machine?

Answer (score 10):

No you can install Asterisk on any virtual machine, it works fine for me. I think your virtual machine is not properly configured. I recommend you to check that first